# What do Ruby's printf arguments mean?

Tags: ruby, printf

Can someone please help me understand the following expression?

```
printf("%3d - %s\n", counter, name)
```

That line prints something like this `6 - Install Adobe software`

I have looked up information and read the reference but I can't find a simple answer and I'm a bit confused. If you can refer me to a good reference, please do so.

`%3d` Ok, according to what I could understand, `%3d` is the number of characters or spaces. Please point me to a reference that explains it.

`%s\n` I couldn't figure out what this does. I guess `\n` is a newline or something similar, but by looking at the output it doesn't seem to work like that.

Why are `counter` and `name` variables separated by commas?

By looking at the output is seems that `%3d` is kind of replaced by `counter` and `%s\n` is replaced by `name`. I'm not sure how it works but I would like to understand it.

Comment: nope, come from a html/css php background. doing RoR for a while now too, and trying to learn Ruby more in depth.

Comment: @texasbruce as you can see not everyone comes from C. It's never stated as a precondition to learn Ruby. There is no "C" tag on the question. hence you comments are irrelevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For syntax look at any printf docs, but check the [sprintf docs on ruby-doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

They're separated by commas because they're separate parameters to the function, but that's more or less syntactic sugar. Think varargs.

Not sure what you mean with the `%s\n` thing, it's a string then a newline: that's what it outputs.

If your question is specifically "how does the code turn a formatting string and a group of arguments into output" I'd probably search for source, for example, a [tiny embedded printf](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/index.html). Nutshell version is that the format string is searched for formatting options, they consume their associated parameters, outputting an appropriately-formatted string. It's a tiny little DSL.

Comment: +1 And the [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) version has the examples formatted correctly - you might want to link there instead.